# VideoView doesn't scale content to match its parent

Tags: android

I am using the DraggablePanel library (https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) to facilitate a YouTube like video player.  If you are not familiar with this feature it basically allows the user to shrink the currently playing video into a small thumbnail that is docked into the corner of the screen.

Unfortunately (and I am not so sure this is an issue with the above library) I have noticed that if I apply an X and Y scale on the parent view of a VideoView, the VideoView itself will not resize its content to match.

See below screenshots, where VideoView is at its natural scale and then with its parent view scaled down to about 0.6:0.6.  You should notice that in the scaled screenshot the VideoView has cropped its content instead of resizing to fit.

[image: VideoView properly scaled 1:1]

[image: VideoView parent scaled to 0.6:0.6]

So I tried to force a width and height on the VideoView as its parent's scale changed.  There are a few examples on the internet about overriding the dimensions of a VideoView - but here is my simple version:

```
public class ScalableVideoView extends VideoView {

    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;

    public ScalableVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScalableVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScalableVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {
            // If a custom dimension is specified, force it as the measured dimension
            setMeasuredDimension(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void changeVideoSize(int width, int height) {
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;

        getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);

        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

The fragment that contains the VideoView is responsible for calling changeVideoSize on it when it receives a notification from the DraggablePanel library about a change in scale.  At which point I calculate a new pair of width and height based on the provided scale values. (scale is from 0f to 1f)

```
public void setVideoViewScale(float scaleX, float scaleY) {
        if (mMaxVideoWidth == 0) {
            mMaxVideoWidth = mVideoView.getWidth();
        }

        if (mMaxVideoHeight == 0) {
            mMaxVideoHeight = mVideoView.getHeight();
        }

        if (mMaxVideoWidth > 0) {

            mVideoView.changeVideoSize((int) (scaleX * mMaxVideoWidth),
                    (int) (scaleY * mMaxVideoHeight));
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this causes some really interesting results.  It seems that the Video portion of the VideoView is scaling appropriately - but the bounds of the VideoView seem to be scaling too fast (causing the video to both shrink and crop).

[image: ScalingVideoView at 0.5 scale]

For further demonstration here are two videos:

- https://github.com/npike/so_scalevideoview/blob/master/demo_videos/so_videoview_noscale.mp4
- https://github.com/npike/so_scalevideoview/blob/master/demo_videos/so_videoview_scale.mp4

I have also uploaded this sample project to GitHub so that you can see the complete code:
https://github.com/npike/so_scalevideoview

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with my app, so I took your example that is much simpler, and tried to fix it.
This is the code that fixes the problem. Edit your changeVideoSize(int width, int height) method to:

```
public void changeVideoSize(int width, int height){
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    setLayoutParams(lp);

    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}
```

With the invalidation of the view you force the VideoView to redraw the whole View with the new layout parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I believe VideoView does not support scaling. Within the sample app that comes with DraggablePanel, there is a VideoSampleActivity, which demonstrates a draggable video. In order to achieve an effect like scaling, the top_view_resize attribute is set to true within activity_video_sample.xml:

```
  <com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:draggable_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/draggable_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  draggable_view:top_view_id="@+id/video_view"
  draggable_view:bottom_view_id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
  draggable_view:top_view_x_scale_factor="@dimen/x_scale_factor"
  draggable_view:top_view_y_scale_factor="@dimen/y_scale_factor"
  draggable_view:top_view_height="@dimen/top_fragment_height"
  draggable_view:top_view_margin_right="@dimen/top_fragment_margin"
  draggable_view:top_view_margin_bottom="@dimen/top_fragment_margin"
  draggable_view:enable_minimized_horizontal_alpha_effect="false"
  draggable_view:top_view_resize="true"
  android:background="@color/black">
```

Setting top_view_resize to true causes the TransformerFactory to return a ResizeTransformer instead of a ScaleTransformer. The ResizeTransformer uses setLayoutParams() to resize the associated View, where the ScaleTransformer applies a scale factor.

Rather than attempting to scale the VideoView, you should be able to set top_view_resize to true.

Note: if you use a DraggablePanel (which supports top and bottom fragments) instead of a DraggableView, you currently do not have access to the top_view_resize attribute of the DraggableView that's nested inside the DraggablePanel. I consider this to be a bug, and I'm hoping I can work with Pedro to expose a top_view_resize attribute on DraggablePanel that will pass its value through to the nested DraggableView. As a result of this bug, DraggablePanel always uses the default Transformer, which is the ScaleTransformer -- which does not work with a VideoView.